# Center two fonts with different different sizes vertically in an NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I use `NSAttributedString` to generate a string with two different sizes. By default, its bottom alignment looks like this:

[image: baseline aligned sizes]

But I want to center it vertically, like this:
[image: vertically centered sizes]

To be clear, this is a single attributed string, not two or more. This is a simplified example to describe my question, what I'd actually like to do is more complex.

Comment: have you considered using two separate views for that? So, for example have two `UILabel`s and after sizing them, align their frames centerY. It seems much cleaner to me than messing around with font sizes and baseline offsets.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

I'd say the easiest thing to do is just manipulate the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` attribute for the text in question:

> `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`
>
> The value of this attribute is an NSNumber object containing a floating point value indicating the character’s offset from the baseline, in points. The default value is 0.

To center, you'd take the difference between height of the large text and the height of the smaller text and halve it, then use that as the baseline adjustment.

Comment: It's now `NSAttributedStringKey.baselineOffset`

Comment: And now it's `NSAttributedString.Key.baselineOffset`

Answer (score 24):

Here is a working example to vertically align smaller text using `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName`.

```
NSString *bigString   = @"BIG";
NSString *smallString = @"Small String";
NSString *fullString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", bigString, smallString];

NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:fullString];

NSRange bigStringRange = NSMakeRange(0, bigString.length);
NSRange smallStringRange = NSMakeRange(bigStringRange.length, smallString.length);

[string beginEditing];


//Set big string font and size
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
               value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:28.0]
               range:bigStringRange];

//set small string font and size
[string addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName
               value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:18.0]
               range:smallStringRange];

//Set small string baseline offset
[string addAttribute:NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName
               value:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0]  //adjust this number till text appears to be centered
               range:smallStringRange];

[string endEditing];
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is more like a trial and error hack, not a real solution. But this can be a solution if combined with some math on-the-fly.

Comment: Well, it works as it is. You just need to figure out baseline value which should not take more than a couple of tries.

Comment: Of course, even if you grab all the font metrics and do the right thing, you potentially have to recompute the baseline offset for every range in the string as soon as you add a single character in a different size....

Comment: Never trust a programmer who won’t use a hack once in a while…

Answer (score 12):

[YasT's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26561522/3151675) in Swift:

**Swift 4**

```
let bigString = "BIG"
let smallString = "Small String"
let fullString = "\(bigString) \(smallString)"
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString)

let bigStringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: bigString.utf16.count)
let smallStringRange = NSRange(location: bigStringRange.length + 1, length: smallString.utf16.count)

let bigStringFontSize: CGFloat = 28
let smallStringFontSize: CGFloat = 18

string.beginEditing()

string.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: bigStringFontSize), range: bigStringRange)
string.addAttribute(.font, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: smallStringFontSize), range: smallStringRange)
string.addAttribute(.baselineOffset, value: (bigStringFontSize - smallStringFontSize) / 2, range: smallStringRange)

string.endEditing()
```

**Swift 3**

```
let bigString = "BIG"
let smallString = "Small String"
let fullString = "\(bigString) \(smallString)"
let string = NSMutableAttributedString(string: fullString)

let bigStringRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: bigString.utf16.count)
let smallStringRange = NSRange(location: bigStringRange.length + 1, length: smallString.utf16.count)

let bigStringFontSize: CGFloat = 28
let smallStringFontSize: CGFloat = 18

string.beginEditing()

string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: bigStringFontSize), range: bigStringRange)
string.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: smallStringFontSize), range: smallStringRange)
string.addAttribute(NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName, value: (bigStringFontSize - smallStringFontSize) / 2, range: smallStringRange)

string.endEditing()
```

Answer (score 3):

Better solution is calculating NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName from fonts typography (short article https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2015/08/advanced-ios-typography/)

Set attribute for second part of attributed string.

```
secondPartAttributes[NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName] = @((firstFont.xHeight - secondFont.xHeight)/2);
```

Comment: Very nice [article](https://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2015/08/advanced-ios-typography/) you referenced there! Even more adorable would be a `NSAttributedString` extension which extracts the biggest `fontSize` from the attributes of a given object and adjusts the baseline of all the other ranges with smaller fonts like your example indicates and returns that `NSMutableAttributedString`. I hope to have time for something like that soon.

Comment: You should use capHeight, not xHeight.