# Vertically aligning NSTextAttachment in NSMutableAttributedString

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, nsattributedstring

I'm adding an icon to a `UILabel` using `NSTextAttachment` inside an `NSMutableAttributedString` like this:

```
//Setting up icon
let moneyIcon = NSTextAttachment()
moneyIcon.image = UIImage(named: "MoneyIcon")
let moneyIconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: moneyIcon)

//Setting up text
let balanceString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " 1,702,200")
balanceString.insert(moneyIconString, at: 0)

//Adding string to label
self.attributedText = balanceString
self.sizeToFit()
```

But for some reason the icon isn't vertically aligned

Does anybody know how can I align it?

Thank you!

Comment: [Check out this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19487369/center-two-different-size-fonts-vertically-in-an-nsattributedstring), which is about two differently sized fonts, but should give you an idea.

Comment: @the4kman Unfortunately it doesn't help. What you've sent is about font sizes, and the icon doesn't have a font size of course... Any other idea?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? Put up the "text"? Then use the `NSBaselineOffsetAttributeName` for the `balanceString`. Or put down the image? Then change the `bounds` of `moneyIcon`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26105803/center-nstextattachment-image-next-to-single-line-uilabel

Answer (score 20, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19780643/3151675), which is about vertically centering two differently sized fonts in a single `NSAttributedString`, mentions using the baseline offset to calculate the center of the string.

You can use the same approach when using an image:

1. Subtract the font size from the image's height and divide it by 2.
2. Subtract the font's descender from the value (since font size isn't the same as the ascent of your font). The font that you are particularly using (**Baloo-Regular**) has a descender value that differs from the standard and it should be divided by 2. Other fonts (including San Fransisco) don't need that fix or require a different divisor.

This code covers most cases, if your font behaves differently, you should check out [the guide for managing texts in Text Kit](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/CustomTextProcessing/CustomTextProcessing.html).

```swift
// *Setting up icon*

let moneyIcon = NSTextAttachment()

// If you're sure a value is not and will never be nil, you can use "!".
// Otherwise, avoid it.

let moneyImage = UIImage(named: "MoneyIcon")!

moneyIcon.image = moneyImage
let moneyIconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: moneyIcon)

// *Setting up NSAttributedString attributes*

let balanceFontSize: CGFloat = 16

let balanceFont = UIFont(name: "Baloo", size: balanceFontSize)!

let balanceBaselineOffset: CGFloat = {
    let dividend =  moneyImage.size.height - balanceFontSize

    return dividend / 2 - balanceFont.descender / 2
}()

let balanceAttr: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: balanceFont,
    .baselineOffset: balanceBaselineOffset
]

// *Setting up text*

let balanceString = NSMutableAttributedString(
    string: " 1,702,200",
    attributes: balanceAttr
)

balanceString.insert(moneyIconString, at: 0)
```

Comment: Try to experiment with different baseline offsets to achieve the desired reeult.

Comment: Please include the code that you’ve tried in your answer.

Comment: I've tried what you've added. I've also tried changing the font size with `self.frame.size.height` and swapping the `-` with `+`. Nothing worked

Comment: @FS.O6 You were right, my approach was not perfect. I tweaked the code a little bit and also added a GitHub project where you can try it out.

Comment: Now the icon is much lower. I've edited my question with a screenshot of the result, please take a look

Comment: Can you provide the name of the font you’re using?

Comment: Yes. It's "Baloo-Regular". Size: 16

Answer (score 33):

use `bounds` property of `NSTextAttachment`.

```
//Setting up icon
let moneyIcon = NSTextAttachment()
moneyIcon.image = UIImage(named: "MoneyIcon")

let imageSize = moneyIcon.image!.size
moneyIcon.bounds = CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: (font.capHeight - imageSize.height) / 2, width: imageSize.width, height: imageSize.height)

let moneyIconString = NSAttributedString(attachment: moneyIcon)

//Setting up text
let balanceString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: " 1,702,200")
balanceString.insert(moneyIconString, at: 0)

//Adding string to label
self.attributedText = balanceString
self.sizeToFit()
```

Comment: This one worked flawlessly. I had issues with setting the offset value properly.

Comment: @FS.O6 this should be the accepted answer. It's so much simpler and just works.