# center NSAttributed string to image NSTextAttachment

Tags: swift4

I have a NSMutableAttributedString string and a NSTextAttachment() image.

The text displays at the bottom of the image. Is there a way to get the text centered in the image?

```
    let fullString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Acceptance")
    let image1 = NSTextAttachment()
    image1.image = UIImage(named: "pos")

    image1.setImageHeight(height:30)

    let image1String = NSAttributedString(attachment: image1)

    fullString.append(image1String)
```

I do have a NSTextAttachment extension for scaling the image down and plays no part in why the text isn't centered

```
extension NSTextAttachment {
func setImageHeight(height: CGFloat) {
    guard let image = image else { return }
    let ratio = image.size.width / image.size.height

    bounds = CGRect(x: bounds.origin.x, y: bounds.origin.y, width: ratio * height, height: height)
}
}
```

This is what it looks like

[image]

**EDIT:** I got it figured out. I will include this because it m ay help someone else out in the future.

```
image1.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: -10, width: 35, height: 35)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vertically aligning NSTextAttachment in NSMutableAttributedString](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47844721/vertically-aligning-nstextattachment-in-nsmutableattributedstring)

Comment: I can't get their examples to work. They are not complete. What is font.capHeight?  font is not even defined.

Comment: every example doesn't work. Something always in red and things are not defined. What is balanceFont.descender? because its RED and not defined.

Comment: None of those examples compile so you are not helping me

Comment: That link didn't help and absolutely did not answer my questions. None of those examples even compile.